# How do I access a model's attribute from inside of the model's function

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I want to access an attribute of a model from within a function. Take a look at the line `if(len(self.order_line) > 0):`

How do I do this correctly? Because the code above doesn't work.

The purpose of this function field is to read and modify another attribute of the same model which is the `order_line`. So it acts as a bridge to simplify the ui, the user only need to specify a property unit to represent the `order_line`. So I need to access the said `order_line` from within the function.

And I also want to SET the `order_line` value based on the `property_unit_rel` value BEFORE the creation of `sale.order`. How do I do that within the `_property_unit_inv` function?

Overall code:

```
from osv import osv,fields

class custom_sale_order(osv.osv):

    _name               = "sale.order"
    _inherit            = 'sale.order'

    def _property_unit_read(self, cr, uid, ids, property_unit_rel, arg, context):
        if(len(self.order_line) > 0):
            pass
        else:
            return None

    def _property_unit_inv(self, cr, uid, ids, property_unit_rel, arg, context):
        pass

    #this will simplify the need of defining a sale_order_line
    _columns = {
        'property_unit_rel' : fields.function(
                    _property_unit_read,
                    fnct_inv = _property_unit_inv,                  
                    type='many2one',
                    obj="property.unit",
                    method=True,
                    string='Property'
                ),
    }

    _defaults = {
    }

    _sql_constraints = [
    ]

    def init(self, cr):
    pass   

custom_sale_order()
```

Answer (score 1):

Most methods you call in OpenERP have parameters self, cr, uid, ids, ....
`self` is pool (see object pool pattern), `cr` is database cursor, `uid` is user id and `ids` is id or list of ids of objects you call method for. If you want to get number of order lines you must get order object at first. You can do it with `a=self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)` to get object (or objects) specified by `ids`.
If `ids` is `int` or `long` you'll get `browse_record` but if it's list you'll get iterable `browse_record_list` (list of browse records). To get lines of some order you can call `a.order_line` (or `a[0].order_line` if `ids` was a list).

So if you can get an attribute of object you have to call it for browse_record.

Comment: Not only I want to get the `order_line` I also want to set them too. How do I do that in the `_property_unit_inv`. Remember that this is BEFORE the creation of the `sale.order` object.

Comment: For fields with `_classic_write==False` (for example function) OpenERP calls `set` method after creation of object. For function fields set method calls fnct_inv method. It passes ids as `int` not `list`.

Comment: So it calls the `_property_unit_inv` after the creation of a new `sale.order`? Is there anyway where I can call it before the creation? Because I want to be able to use the existing creation method.

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself bad. Method `create` creates object in database table (with `INSERT INTO...`) and after it (when it has id of created object) calls method from `fnct_inv`. If you want to do something before creating object in table you should overwrite `create` method.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that I can simply override the `create` method. But I thought that the purpose of fnct_inv is to link the field to something that I specify before the creation of the object. Maybe because I assumed that python is object oriented. Turns out that I was wrong. Then what's the purpose of `fnct_inv`. Why don't we just override the `create` method?